# Advanced Eloquent query with custom pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Here's one for you gurus.
I have 4 tables. Users, Chefs, Locations, Types.

**users table**

```
id
etc
```

**chefs table**

```
id
user_id
etc
```

**locations table**

```
id
zip
etc
```

**types table**

```
id
type_name
etc
```

Every Chef account created is a User.  Every User account created is not necessarily a Chef.  There are other types but I omit for simplicity.

**Chef and User Models**

```
class Chef extends Eloquent {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function chef() {
        return $this->hasOne('Chef');
    }
}
```

the 'users' table has a many to many relationship with the 'locations' table.  I also included 'type_id' in the 'location_user' pivot table.

**location_user pivot table**

```
id
location_id
user_id
type_id
```

**Location Model**

```
class Location extends Eloquent {
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withTimestamps()->withPivot(['type_id']);
    }
}
```

My goal is to return all Chef id's for a particular 'zip', a field which resides in the 'locations' table.
A bit more information - one of the type_id values available in the pivot table is '0'.  This represents the default Location should the User who became a Chef not want to create a separate Location for his Chef account.  Every User has one of these, a corresponding pivot (location_user) entry with type_id = 0.  If a User desires a separate Location as a Chef, a separate 'location' table entry is created and is linked by a separate pivot table entry with type_id = 2.  That way the system knows which Location to use.  Should a Chef account exist for a particular User but not accompanied by a pivot account with type_id = 2, then the Location that the pivot account (with that user_id and type_id = 0) links to is used instead.

This is part of my search code:

```
        if ($city_search || $zip_search) {
            $chef_ids = array();
            // TODO: Possibly bad for scaling.  Find a single Eloquent call for this
            $locations = Location::with('users')
                ->where('zip', 'LIKE', "%$city_search%")
                ->where('zip', 'LIKE', "%$zip_search%")
                ->get();
            foreach ($locations as $loc) {
                foreach ($loc->users as $user) {
                    $chef_ids[] = $user->chef->id;
                }
            }
        }

        if (count($chef_ids) == 0) return NULL;
```

The problem is that, if a single User is also a Chef with his Chef Location as the default but also has another [type other than Chef] Location, then there would be 2 records for this User in the pivot table, one with type_id = 0 (serving both the default and Chef locations) and the other with type_id = ?.  If the default Location is not of the queried 'zip' value but the other one is, then that Chef's id would be returned.
For clarity, the flow would be like this:
get all Locations with zip = ?. Get all Users from pivot table.

*One of the users IS also a Chef HOWEVER his Chef account uses the default Location (the record in the pivot table with type_id = 0.  There is no pivot record with his user_id value and type_id = 2).*

Get the chefs and then their ids from all these Users.  Does this User have a pivot account with a location_id containing the queried zip value? Yes (for another type). Does this User have a Chef account?  Yes. Then his chef_id is returned even though his Chef account uses the default Location in another zip.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$locations = Location::with('users.chef') [etc..]
```